# Flask / jwt_extended import custom override default behaviors, How to import?

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt-extended

Using:  Flask, jwt_extended

**Background**

As my code/test project has grown, I've split it into several routes, and have run into a problem with custom overrides for jwt_extended.

These routes are loaded from:

```
**File:  .../__init__.py** (project root)

...
from app.routes import default, user, post, ...
...
```

I have successfully used the changing default behavior outlined in
https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changing_default_behavior/

to override jwt_extended's default, for example expired tokens.

**Problem:**

The @jwt.xyz_loader overrides need to be in the same file as the routes they're being used on.  This creates code duplication, and I'm sure it shouldn't need to be like this.

**Question:**

How can the @jwt.xyz_loader functions overrides be loaded from a separate file?

Code samples - working (when @jwt.xyz_loader is in the same file as the route it's being used with, here via @jwt_required:

```
**File:  .../routes/default.py**    

...
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager,, jwt_required, current_user, unset_jwt_cookies, ...
jwt = JWTManager(app)

@jwt.user_lookup_loader
def user_lookup_callback(_jwt_header, jwt_data):
    identity = jwt_data["sub"]
    return User.query.filter_by(public_id=identity).one_or_none()

@jwt.invalid_token_loader
def invalid_token_loader(jwt_data):
    flash('Please log in.')
    response = redirect(url_for('login', next=request.path))
    unset_jwt_cookies(response)
    return response
...    
@app.route("/profile/", methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required(optional=True)
def profile():
...
```

**Tried:**

Importing jwt from a file, where the @jwt.xyz_loaders are with the JWT when it's defined.  But these fail to override the default behavior when the JWT is used.

```
**File:  .../auth/web.py**

from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, current_user, JWTManager, set_access_cookies, unset_jwt_cookies, get_jwt, decode_token
jwt = JWTManager(app)

def user_lookup_callback(_jwt_header, jwt_data):
    identity = jwt_data["sub"]
    return User.query.filter_by(public_id=identity).one_or_none()

@jwt.user_lookup_loader
def user_lookup_callback(_jwt_header, jwt_data):
    identity = jwt_data["sub"]
    return User.query.filter_by(public_id=identity).one_or_none()

@jwt.expired_token_loader
def my_expired_token_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):

...
```

```
**File:  .../routes/default.py**   

from app.auth.web import jwt

...    
@app.route("/profile/", methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required(optional=True)
def profile():
...
```

The JWT is loaded, but without the @jwt.xyz_loader overrides defined in auth.py.

**Also tried:**

Using jwt.init_app(app) in **init**.py in project root where routes, db etc are loaded.  Even if defined here, @jwt.xyz_loader functions do not override jwt_extended default behaviors.  These still can only be overridden when referencing @jwt.xyz_loader in the same route as the JWT is being used, for example @jwt_required.

**Question:** (restating, in case lost in the middle above)

How can the @jwt.xyz_loader function jwt_extended default behavior overrides be loaded from a separate file?

Comment: If anyone happens to come across this:

Comment: If anyone happens to come across this, not solved as intended, but a solution nonetheless:  Use 'g' for current_user.  Define callback functions as you'd like in a dedicated file, where flask_jwt_extended et al are imported.  Include a  @before_request function with g.current_user = current_user.  If, as me, you're seeking different callback overrides for different routes (e.g. web, api), call a different file.  Good enough.